# How to convert raw rsa key to RFC 7468 format in php

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa, sha

I have public key and private key in raw string format like

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1WWRykdXuvMOnRyYCesJpozgaRSoA....
```

I want to convert this to below format

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
........................
........................
........................
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In the php **openssl_get_privatekey** not able to read public and private key from raw string

**If is there any other way to read private and public key from the raw string in php, Please let me how i can do this.**

Comment: It is not raw, it seems like base64 encoded, or something else?

Comment: Can you post the public key so we can see the structure?  It may be as simple as copying it between the `BEGIN` and `END`.